# differentiable map on a connected open set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable mapping on a connected open set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ and if $f'(x)=0$ for every $x\in E$, prove that $f$ is constant in $E$.

For simplicity, take $n=2$. To prove $f(x)=f(a)$ for fixed $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and 
arbitrary $x=(x_1,x_2)$

See that 
$|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|\leq |f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)|+|f(a_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|$

As $f'=0$, we see that partial derivatives are also zero.

So, by theory of one variable, we see that if $x_1$ is near $a_1$, 
we have $f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)=0$.

For similar reason, if $x_2$ is near $a_2$
then $f(a_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)=0$.

So, we then see that $f(x_1,x_2)=f(a_1,a_2)$
for $(x_1,x_2)$ close to $(a_1,a_2)$.

Thus, $\{(x_1,x_2):f(x_1,x_2)=f(a_1,a_2)\}$ is open and it is clearly closed as well.

Thus, by connectedness of $E$ we see that $\{(x_1,x_2):f(x_1,x_2)=f(a_1,a_2)\}=E$...

I am trying to solve problems from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis and not sure about this solution... Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the solution...

Comment: $f$ is constant if and only if each component of $f$ is constant. Hint: Use mean value theorem.

Comment: Why mean value theorem? I would like to know what is wrong in this method... @luka5z

Comment: You need to justify the claim that $\{(x_1,x_2):f(x_1,x_2)=f(a_1,a_2)\}$ is both closed and open in more rigorous way (if this is true). You did not convince me at all :)

Comment: I do not understand what else is necessary to say so... Given $(a_1,a_2)$ there exists some $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ where $\delta_1$ comes from $x_1$ and $\delta_2$ from $x_2$ such that when $|(x_1,x_2)-(a_1,a_2)<\delta|$ then $f(x_1,x_2)=f(a_1,a_2)$ and so  that set is open... Closedness is clear as that set is zero set of the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$...

Comment: @luka5z : Please see above comment

Comment: FIrst of all your notation is sloppy. Remember that $f$ is a vector field... And  "by theory of one variable, we see that if $x_1$ is near $a_1$, we have$f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)=0$" is clearly the mean value theorem applied to the first variable. $x_1$ does not even have to be "near" $a_1$ as long as the whole line segment connecting those points lies in $E$.

Comment: Notation is sloppy i guess.. But otherwise is this fine? @luka5z

Comment: @kklm You are using limiting value to show that some neighbourhood also possesses same value!! That's the flaw in your whole argument.

Comment: @kklm If you want proof of this theorem, then I suggest you that it is given in Apostol's Mathematical analysis on pg.356 (Theorem 12.10).

Comment: @VikrantDesai : Why is that a wrong way to do this problem?

Comment: A function has a value at a point doesn't mean that there exists a neighbourhood around that point such that all the points in the neighborhood 'take' that same value. And you are ignoring this fact.

Comment: @VikrantDesai : Ok, I got it