# Continuous function on connected set is constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, connectedness

I have asked one question previously [differentiable map on a connected open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598433/differentiable-map-on-a-connected-open-set) which says :

$f$ is differentiable on $E$ and $E$ is open, conencted  and $f'(x)=0$ for every $x\in E$ then  $f$ is constant on $E$.

There i arrived at a condition that $\{(x,y):f(x,y)=f(a,b)\}$ is an open set and as this is clearly closed, i said we have a contradiction for connectedness and concluded that $\{(x,y):f(x,y)=f(a,b)\}=E$ and so $f$ is constant.

I was wondering why can't i use same technique for just continuous function.. for continuous function also given a point there exists an open set whose image is same as that of given point...

I do not know what is wrong.. In this way any continuous function on a connected set has to be constant..

Please let me know what is wrong...

Comment: How do you know that there exists an open set whose image is same as that of given point?

Comment: @VikrantDesai $f$ is continuous if $\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)$... I belive this says that if i am near $(x,y)$ image is same..

Comment: No, it just means that if you are near $(x,y)$ then the image is near $f(x,y)$ -- *near*, not the same.  As regards your proposition that "for continuous function also given a point there exists an open set whose image is same as that of given point", consider $f(x)=x$ on the real line.

Comment: That's not true. It means that as $(h,k) \to (0,0)$, the limiting value is $f(x,y)$. For example, as $x \to 0$, $f(x)=x \to 0$. But can you give me a point,in this case, which is different from $0$(in domain) such that $f(x)=0?$

Comment: @ForgotALot : Yes Yes... I got it